# localHost 3000 showing blank page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, web-applications

I am trying to write my first web app with React and Node. I have written some JS and CSS for a component called Banner and rendered it in App.js, but when I save my changes, the change is not reflected on localhost:3000 which just shows a blank page.

The only time I got the localhost:3000 to show anything was when I wrote some text in HTML p tags in the body of the index.html. Then, the browser displayed the text.

I have also tried moving the id=root from index.html to App.js. That did not work.
Please, what am I doing wrong? How do I get the browser to display my components?

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

import React from 'react'

function Banner() {
  return (
    <div className="banner">
      <h1> Some Text that goes on Banner </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Banner from './components/Banner';
import Exhibit from './components/Exhibit'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Router>
          <Banner />
        </Router>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```css
.banner {
    height: 30vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #b300b3;
}

.banner > h1 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"> 
    <title>Title of Web App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How you're using `Router` maybe the issue. Do you get output if you simply return `<Banner />` from `<App />`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to be more minimal in this level.
Only use banner component in App.js file.
delete router and <> </> in App.js file.

Comment: Thank you, but that did not work. Please, is there anything else I might try?

Answer (score 1):

replace `class App extends Component`  with `class App extends React.Component`
or add `import { Component } from 'react'`